# How do I communicate with a SAML 2.0 server so that I can leverage it's authentication?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I need to set up my .Net 5 web app so that it can connect to a SAML 2.0 login server at this internal site: [**login.antares.eng.edu**].

I am using this library to help me: https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2

I followed the directions on that site and added the required code to my `Startup.cs` and added an `AuthController.cs` controller,
but now I am unsure of how to proceed next.

To try and educate myself on how to work with SAML, I loaded up a website at
[**starmaps.cosmos.n.edu**] that I know uses the same SAML 2.0 login server that I need to use [**login.antares.eng.edu**].

When I first load the website, **starmaps.cosmos.n.edu**, it automatically goes to the SAML server at: **login.antares.eng.edu**

Using the browser developer tools, I can see the following is being sent:

> ```
> https://login.antares.eng.edu/idp/profile/SAML2/Redirect/SSO?SAMLRequest=aZZAbsIwEEV%2FJwI%2BcUh5pWQgUVBVJNpGhHbRTWWcASwltuaZ9PH3dYBWdNOVrdHc11NnPEbZ1E4MWjqYNby3gBQsFxP2msut2g3VVZzK4SDu96GK81F6He%2F6w1GeVpm82gKLnsGjtmbCsiRl0RKxhaVBkoZCKc2yuNeLs3zTuxaDXKSjJO2%2FsGgRHtFG0lF4IHIoOHcS0VlPidNECVQt15XjztudroGXs%2FtVxtdQaQ%2BKeFk%2BsujWegVH8AnbyRqhAyiCjX6H30rhLVll6xttKm32E9Z6I6xEjcLIBlCQEp25CAHE9tSE4m6zKeLisdywaIYIvkOdW4NtA74E%2F64VPK1XF%2FAd88EiQZU4aawjmyjb8YT0D%2BcekHesfRT52iQS3SeLPpvaoDhu4H6wd02BpuOuWxwH7S%2F0%2F4vlTwY1LQLpmWrML3xOxk21BPFyUdhaq69oVtf2Y%2B5RRhgo%2BTbMk09Psr9fZvoN&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fstarmaps.cosmos.n.edu%2FMapperRun%2FPages%2FMain.aspx
> ```

I am not exactly sure what is going on, but I need my web app to do the same.

How can I get my web app using the ITfoxtec library to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decorate the controller or action with the [Authorize] attribute to require authentication and automatically start the login sequence.

Like this in the sample:
https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L15

Alternatively, you can add this requirement generally in Startup.cs/Program.cs.

Comment: I see, so I will do that, but where do I put the code that connects to the saml server at `https://login.antares.eng.edu`?  Thank you!

Comment: In configuration https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/appsettings.json and read in startup.cs https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestWebAppCore/Startup.cs#L32